# drupal multisite migration not working

Tags: multi-sites, configuration

I tried to change the domain name of the existing site and now when I try to access the domain, it comes up with the drupal install screen.

Initially the domain name was ***stage.othercompany.com*** and now I changed the domain name to ***stage.mycompany.com***. I changed the folder mapping in sites.php and cleared all the cache in the Drupal database. I have also restarted the Apache server but still I get only the install screen. Please help with this issue. Is there any other setting that I have to change? I have also changed the $base_url variable in settings.php in the respective multi site folder.

Update:

I checked the file_managed and file_usage table and both are empty.

I tried creating a directory called stage.mycompany.com under stage with all the module, theme,files folder and setting files from stage.othercompany.com folder and it seems to work now. I also tried with a symlink to the folder and that works as well.

My doubt now is that drupal is not honouring the sites.php. Can can one point me in the right direction please.

**sites.php**

$sites['stage.mycompany.com'] = 'example.com';

and the folders in **sites directory** are

all, default and example.com

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you share your sites.php contest, also what is the default folders name in sites directory?

Comment: Hi @ram4nd I had updated my question with the code in sites.php and directory names in sites folder. kindly help me on this regards. Thank you.

Comment: Just a quick observation... You said you changed the `$base_url` variable inside the file `setting.php` -- was that a typo? If not, the file needs to be called `settings.php`, and the line with the database info needs to be overwritten to point to your existing database. Otherwise you'll get the install screen every time.

Comment: Hi @jerdiggity. I checked the $base_url value once again and it seems to be fine. setting.php was a typo. The name is correct in the server. I would like to use the same database, so I didn change any variables in the database array.

Comment: Do you have the symbolic link done? You can create symlink with php if you don't have ssh access. It should be
$sites['stage.mycompany.com'] = 'stage.mycompany.com'; Also the folder name should be stage.mycompany.com and remove default. Maybe you can find this helpful: [Drupal 7 multi-site on localhost](http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/drupal-7-multi-site-localhost)

Comment: Just create stage.mycompany.com folder under sites and point the sub domain stage.mycompany.com to the root folder of Drupal as usual. Nothing else is required. I've done this on Centos/Cpanel though.